# Objective-C passing around ... nil terminated argument lists

Tags: objective-c, variadic

Having some issues with the `...` in ObjectiveC.

I'm basically wrapping a method and want to accept a `nil` terminated list and directly pass that same list to the method I am wrapping.

Here's what I have but it causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.  Inspecting the local vars, it appears when `otherButtonTitles` is simply a `NSString` when it is passed in with `otherButtonTitles:@"Foo", nil]`

```
+ (void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title
              message:(NSString *)message
             delegate:(id)delegate
    cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
    otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:delegate
                                           cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                           otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles] autorelease];
    [alert show];
}
```

How do I simply siphon from the argument incoming to the argument outgoing, preserving the exact same `nil` terminated list?

Comment: The first object in a variadic method list is not part of the va_list itself, which is why you see otherButtonTitles as an NSString.  That is, the va_list only comprises the objects in the "..." part.

Comment: Since Objective-C is a superset of C, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't do this, at least not in the way you're wanting to do it.  What you want to do (pass on the variable arguments) requires having an initializer on `UIAlertView` that accepts a `va_list`.  There isn't one.  However, you can use the `addButtonWithTitle:` method:

```
+ (void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title
              message:(NSString *)message
             delegate:(id)delegate
    cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
    otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:delegate
                                           cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    if (otherButtonTitles != nil) {
      [alert addButtonWithTitle:otherButtonTitles];
      va_list args;
      va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
      NSString * title = nil;
      while(title = va_arg(args,NSString*)) {
          [alert addButtonWithTitle:title];
      }
      va_end(args);
    }

    [alert show];
}
```

This is, of course, very problem-specific.  The real answer is "you can't implicitly pass on a variable argument list to a method/function that does not have a `va_list` parameter".  You must therefore find a way around the problem.  In the example you gave, you wanted to make an alertView with the titles you passed in.  Fortunately for you, the `UIAlertView` class has a method that you can iteratively call to add buttons, and thereby achieve the same overall effect.  If it did not have this method, you'd be out of luck.

The other really messy option would be to make it a variadic macro.  A variadic macro looks like this:

```
#define SHOW_ALERT(title,msg,del,cancel,other,...) { \
  UIAlertView *_alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:del cancelButtonTitle:cancel otherButtonTitles:other, ##__VA_ARGS__] autorelease]; \
  [_alert show]; \
}
```

However, even with the variadic macro approach, you'd still need a custom macro for each time you wanted to do this.  It's not a very solid alternative.

Comment: A cool approach, but I was hoping to use this technique in other places where a method like this may not exist to help out with the argument list.  Really no way to create a nil terminated list dynamically?

Comment: @Squeegy you can maybe fake a `va_list` (see cocoawithlove link in @Don's comment), but unless the method you want to invoke takes a `va_list` (as opposed to `...`), you can't use it.

Comment: Fortunately, Dave's solution works for your specific situation.

Comment: If you need to accept a list of variable arguments (as Dave answers quite nicely above) and then construct a call to a non-variadic API, use NSInvocation.

Comment: If anyone wants to see this solution in working code, I used it to create a class through which I'll be funneling all my alert-showing needs from now on. Help yourself and/or add improvements at https://github.com/clozach/CLAlertViewManager

Answer (score 0):

<strike>How about constructing an `NSInvocation` object?  Since arguments must be passed by pointer, you could pass the pointer to the nil-terminated list.</strike>

You could also iterate over the parameters using `marg_list()` and construct a nil-terminated list yourself.

These are just simple suggestions; I haven't tried them out.

Comment: "`NSInvocation` does not support invocations of methods with either variable numbers of arguments or `union` arguments." - http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-1804

Comment: Well, that kills that suggestion!

Comment: I think I can something like this to iterate through the list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D but how do I use `marg_list()` to generate one dynamically I can pipe back in.

Comment: Matt Gallagher has a way to create a fake variadic list: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Again, I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to the OP's `UIAlertView`-wrapping case, and tested only on iOS7:  It appears that once a `UIAlertView` has been initialised with `otherButtons:nil`, and then has its style set to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` it doesn't call its delegate's `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` to validate input.  I'm not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour but it broke my principle of least astonishment.  This is reproducible with the following (I'll assume the delegate's `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` is implemented):

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                             message:@"message" 
                                            delegate:self         
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[av addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[av show];
```

The solution, since UIAlertView happily accepts `otherButtons:nil`, is to initialise `UIAlertView` with otherButtonTitles (which can be nil), and iterate over the variadic arguments, as above:

```
+ (void)showWithTitle:(NSString *)title
              message:(NSString *)message
             delegate:(id)delegate
    cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
    otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:delegate
                                           cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                           otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles] autorelease];

    // add your [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput] etc. as required here

    if (otherButtonTitles != nil) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
        NSString * title = nil;
        while(title = va_arg(args,NSString*)) {
            [alert addButtonWithTitle:title];
        }
        va_end(args);
    }

    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: While this is interesting information and should definitely be reported at Apple's [bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/) it is not an answer to this post. As I understand it it does not provide additional information to question asked.

Comment: Already reported.  I agree, in part; it's a correction to the accepted answer in the place Google brought me to when I was struggling with variadic UIAlertView wrapping of my own.  Maybe it will help someone else...