# Is it possible to redirect system API in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

Due to some reasons I have to keep original code without modification, but try to redirect system API into my code and then call back to the original one. For example, I would like to do something more in `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

Now I try to use method swizzling. But it seems that `NSString` is not loaded during the runtime of main, I move swizzling method to `MyAppDelegate`. After that `class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(stringWithFormat:)`) is not nil. However, the swizzling method is still not working because `class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(override_stringWithFormat:))` is still nil, how should I fix that?

Thanks,
clu

```
@interface NSString (MyNSString)

+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;
@end


@implementation NSString (MyNSString)
+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... {
   //do something...
   [NSString stringWithFormat:format];
}
@end
```

Here is the code in MyAppDelegate

```
#import "MyNSString.h"
-(void) MethodSwizzle:(Class)c replaceOrig:(SEL) origSEL withNew:(SEL) overrideSEL {
    Method origMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, origSEL);
    Method overrideMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(c, overrideSEL);

    if(class_addMethod(c, origSEL, method_getImplementation(overrideMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(overrideMethod)))
    class_replaceMethod(c, overrideSEL, method_getImplementation(origMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(origMethod));
else
    method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, overrideMethod);    
}

- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *) options {
    ...
    //Unit test
    NSString *a=[NSString override_stringWithFormat:@"Test"]; //returned something
    Method b = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], @selector(override_stringWithFormat:)); //return nil;

    //do something...
    [self MethodSwizzle:[NSString class] replaceOrig:@selector(stringWithFormat:) withNew:@selector(override_stringWithFormat:)];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you're trying to do, the question is a little bit unclear. Also, don't try to inherit from NSString, it's part of a class cluster so it's a lot more complicated that just overriding one method. You even have to i[mplement the storage yourself](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). Gets complicated real fast.

There are two ways of adding methods to an existing class in Objective-C: [Categories](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ClassCategories) and [method Swizzling](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MethodSwizzling).

Categories allow you to define a new method on an existing class, you cannot *reliably* replace a method using categories. For example:

```
@interface NSString (MyStuff)
- (id)mySpecialInit;
@end;

@implementation NSString (MyStuff)
/* implementation of -(id)mySpecialInit would go here */
@end
```

Again, this method will not reliably replace an existing method on a class.

For that you need method swizzling. Caveat - this is an advanced feature of the runtime, and it's real easy to get yourself into a debugging nightmare, so use with caution. Swizzling allows you to replace the implementation of one method with another method of the same signature. Using some tricks, you can call the super implementation as well. Matt Gallagher is generally credited with having the [best implementation of method swizzling](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/supersequent-implementation.html), as it allows for reliably calling the pre-existing implementation (called supersequent implementation). Take a look at the linked article on Cocoa with Love for example usages. Your edited code probably doesn't work because you're trying to swizzle a class method, but using the getInstanceMethod function. Use class_getClassMethod() instead. Also, you need to rename your category stringWithFormat method, it **must not clash** with the real method name. One last caveat - I've never seen method swizzling used on a method with variadic arguments (...), and [this C q&a](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html) leads me to believe this won't be possible (try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196/objective-c-passing-around-nil-terminated-argument-lists) as a possible solution). As an academic exercise, here is what it would *probably* look like:

**NSString+MyMethods.h**

```
@interface NSString (MyMethods) 
 + (id)clu_stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format,...;
@end
```

**NSString+MyMethods.m:**

```
@implementation NSString (MyMethods) 
+ (id)clu_stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format,... {
  //Do your stuff here
  //call supersequent implementation
  //again, I have no idea if this will work as is, you might need to tweak how it passes the variable argument list
  invokeSupersequent(format); 
}

+(void)load {
  //do your method swizzle in here, this is called one time only
  Method origMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSString class], @selector(stringWithFormat:);
  Method replMethod = class_getClassMethod([NSString class], @selector(clu_stringWithFormat:);

  method_exchangeImplementations(origMethod, replMethod);  
}
```

Given that this is likely impossible, and is a very bad idea otherwise - you're changing how a specific class in a class cluster operates, which Apple says "don't do this". And for good reason - what happens if someones calls [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:], or allocs an NSString and then calls -initWithFormat:? There are a lot of valid paths into creating a string with a format, you'd have a miserable time trying to maintain code which intercepts all of them. I would encourage you to rethink the design of this - whatever problem you're trying to solve, there is likely a much easier and more maintainable way of achieving it. Adding your own String Factory, for example.

Comment: RyanR, thanks for your info. I know categories, but it creates a new method and it's terrible to rewrite my code to use the new one, because I use NSString everywhere. So I'd like to just import my new MyNSString and it will replace existing NSString methods to mine. It's more flexible if I'd like to use the original one. In C++ I can use #typedef to redirect the call such as printf to my owned, but I have no idea how to do it in objective-c.

Comment: Hi RyanR, I had updated my question but still get stuck in swizzling method, do you have any suggestion for this? Thanks again.

Comment: It might be hard to rewrite your code to use a new class, but look at how much trouble you are going through right now to do something that could cause much bigger problems for you down the road.