# Processing varargs before passing them on

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

I'd like to build a function that has the same signature as `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:` (with the varargs), but I'd like to URL encode each argument before I pass it along to `stringWithFormat:` itself. I already have a method `+ (NSString *)urlEncode:(NSString *)s` that does the encoding. How do I build the va_list with the encoded arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C passing around ... nil terminated argument lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196/objective-c-passing-around-nil-terminated-argument-lists)

Answer (score 2):

There's no portable way to build va_lists in C, C++, or Objective-C. You could probably write or find some functions that use inline assembly to modify the stack directly and make variadic calls, but that's really not a good way to go. You have three practical options that I can think of.

Here's the first option. Use mutable strings only and forward the arguments using NSString's initWithFormat:arguments: method.

```
- (NSString*)forwardMessage:(NSString*)format, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    BOOL escape = NO;
    char* ptr = (char*)[format UTF8String];
    while (*ptr) {
        if (*ptr == '%') {
            escape = !escape;
        } else if (escape) {
            // argument
            id obj = va_arg(args, id);
            if (*ptr == '@') {
                // object
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    // string
                    id copy = [obj copy];
                    if (copy != obj) {
                        // mutable
                        [obj replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [obj length]) withString:@"replaced!"];
                    }
                }
            }
            escape = NO;
        }
        ++ptr;
    }

    va_end(args);

    va_list args2;
    va_start(args2, format);

    NSString* ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args2];

    va_end(args2);
    return ret;
}
```

That method will take variadic arguments and will replace the contents of any mutable string with "replaced!". Since we can only read the arguments before forwarding them, we can't actually send different objects to the initWithFormat:arguments: we just have to alter the objects. Be aware that making a copy of the object to test whether or not it's mutable like I did in that method isn't great practice.

Here's your second option. Use NSInvocation to build your new arguments to stringWithFormat:.

```
- (NSString*)forwardMessage:(NSString*)format, ... {
    BOOL escape = NO;
    NSUInteger count = 0;

    char* ptr = (char*)[format UTF8String];
    while (*ptr) {
        if (*ptr == '%') {
            escape = !escape;
        } else if (escape) {
            if (*ptr == '@') {
                // this is an object
            }
            ++count;
            escape = NO;
        }
        ++ptr;
    }

    char* sig = malloc(3 + count + 2);
    memset(sig, '@', 3 + count);
    sig[3 + count] = ':';
    sig[3 + count + 1] = '\0';

    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:sig]];

    free(sig);

    [invocation setTarget:[NSString class]];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(stringWithFormat:)];

    [invocation setArgument:&format atIndex:2];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        void* arg = va_arg(args, void*);
        // arg is an object, you can change it here
        [invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:i + 3];
    }

    [invocation invoke];

    va_end(args);

    id ret;

    [invocation getReturnValue:&ret];

    return ret;
}
```

That method does have one drawback: It won't work when you pass types that have sizes that aren't the same as void* or id. For example, integers work, but floats don't come out right. `[self forwardMessage:@"test %d asd %s %f %@ %d", 2, "asd", 2.897, @"test" 5]` returns `test 2 asd asd 0.000000 test 5`. It wouldn't be too hard to add a bit more logic to make specific types work correctly though.

I'm not sure I can really recommend either of these solutions, but maybe they'll work for your situation.

The third option: If your arguments are only going to be NSString objects, I'm gonna have to recommend abandoning stringWithFormat: and parsing / forming the formatted string yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty difficult to do nicely. The thing is, you can't create a `va_list`; the "functions" `va_start`, `va_end` etc are defined as macros, hiding ugly internal stuff you probably don't want to get your hands dirty with.

If you really want to do it, you could probably parse the contents of the `format` string (shouldn't be awfully difficult, especially if you assume only `%@` are possible formatting specifiers), so you know how many arguments there are in the `va_list`, then `encode` each of them and return the final rebuilt string. You are, of course, sort-of re-implementing stringWithFormat: then, though.

"The Internet" tells me there's no portable way of constructing a `va_list`, but if you could, you would be able to use the following idea:

```
s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:argp] autorelease];
```

I personally think your best bet is just to walk through the string and build up the result, using `va_arg` whenever you encounter the `%@` token.

[edit] This is following on what @daxnitro says here below, the approach I suggested and he calls option 3: it's a quick hack, but for object tokens only, it works.

```
typedef enum {
NORMAL,
TOKEN
} STATE;

+ (NSString *) encodeWithFormat: (id) format, ... {

STATE s = NORMAL;
va_list argp;
va_start(argp, format);
unichar c;
NSString * tmp;
NSMutableString * out = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [format length]; i ++) {

    c = [format characterAtIndex: i];

    // simple state-based recognising
    switch(c) {
    case '%':
        if(s == NORMAL)
            s = TOKEN; // switch to token-mode
        else { // we were accepting tokens, so this is an escaped '%'
            [out appendFormat: @"%c", c];
            s = NORMAL;
        }
        break;
    default:
        if(s == NORMAL) // default case
            [out appendFormat: @"%c", c];
        else // accepting tokens, so check type
            switch(c) {
            case '@': // this is a string placeholder
                tmp = va_arg(argp, NSString*);
                [out appendFormat: @"%@", [Test encode:tmp]]; // your magic here
                s = NORMAL;
                break;
            // you could add cases for %d etc here, if necessary
            default: // some unrecognised placeholder. ignore.
                s = NORMAL;
            break;
            }
        break;
    }
}
va_end(argp);
return [out autorelease];
}
```