# How to properly subclassing a UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiactionsheet

I want subclass a `UIActionSheet` to use a block approach instead of delegate.
My problem is when I call the super initialization on `UIActionSheet` the variadic `...` at the end of the method aren't recognized as a `va_list` and the action sheet only show the first button.

Here class implementation `.m`

```
@interface FLActionSheet ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) actionClickedBlock clickedBlock;
@end

@implementation FLActionSheet

+ (id)actionSheetWithTitle:(NSString *)title
              clickedBlock:(actionClickedBlock)clickedBlock
         cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
    destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle
         otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title
                          clickedBlock:clickedBlock
                     cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
                     otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles];
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
       clickedBlock:(actionClickedBlock)clickedBlock
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:title
                       delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
         destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
              otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles,nil];

    if (self)
    {
        self.clickedBlock = [clickedBlock copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    self.clickedBlock(buttonIndex);
}

@end
```

And here how I initialize the action sheet:

```
[[[FLActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ordina per..."
                            clickedBlock:^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {

                                switch (buttonIndex)
                                {
                                    case 0:

                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Annulla"
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Data crescente", @"Data decrescente", @"Mittente crescente", @"Mittente decrescente"]
     showFromBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem
     animated:YES];
```

And here the result:

[image]

I'm definitely doing something wrong but I do not understand what.
Ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C passing around ... nil terminated argument lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345196/objective-c-passing-around-nil-terminated-argument-lists)

Comment: @MartinR This not really a duplicate. Here the question is _How to properly subclass UIActionSheet?_ The answer is _You better not._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `UIActionSheet` is **not** designed to be **subclassed**.
2. There are **other ways** how to use it with blocks. Best is to create a **category**, that implements delegate protocol and store the block using **associated ojects** mechanism. [Implementation here.](https://bitbucket.org/iAdverti/essentials/src/057997e7a981fcf2154b6f15e9dfdbba6ddeaba4/UIKit/UIActionSheet%2BEssentials.h?at=master)
3. I think `initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:...` is **not** the **designated** initializer and it is implemented using `[self init]` with following `setTitle:` and `addButtonWithTitle:` calls. You should do it similarily.
4. In fact, with variadic method, you have no other option. To **collect all arguments**, you have to use `va_list` and related functions. [Implementation here.](https://bitbucket.org/iAdverti/essentials/src/057997e7a981fcf2154b6f15e9dfdbba6ddeaba4/Foundation/NSArray%2BEssentials.h?at=master#cl-102) Then on each of them you call `addButtonWithTitle:` as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please pass `nil` at the last of your `otherButtonTitles` parameter.

```
[[FLActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ordina per..."
                            clickedBlock:^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {

                                switch (buttonIndex)
                                {
                                    case 0:

                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                       cancelButtonTitle:nil
                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"Annulla"
                       otherButtonTitles:@"Data crescente", @"Data decrescente", @"Mittente crescente", @"Mittente decrescente", nil]
     showFromBarButtonItem:myBarButtonItem
     animated:YES];
```

Comment: - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;