# To invoke a variadic function with unamed arguments of another variadic function

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I have two variadic function as `foo(format, ...)` and `bar(format, ...)`. I want to implement function `foo` so that it can invoke `bar` with the same list of arguments it has. That is,

```
foo(format...)
{
 ...
 bar(format, ...);
}
```

For instance, invoking `foo("(ii)", 1, 2)` will invoke `bar` with same arguments `bar("(ii)", 1, 2)`. How should this `foo` function be implemented?

PS: function `bar` is from a legacy library which I cant change its interface.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but I'm almost willing to bet that you'll find the following standard library functions handy: `vprintf()`, `vfprintf()` and `vsprintf()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can't be done, as long as all you have is a bunch if functions with `...` arguments.

You have to plan ahead for things like that and implement each variadic fuinction in two-staged fashion

```
void vfoo(format, va_list *args) {
  /* Process `*args` */
}

void foo(format, ...) {
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, format);
  vfoo(format, &args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Once you have each of your variadic functions implemented through a pair of `va_list *` function and `...` function, you can delegate the calls using the `va_list *` versions of the functions

```
void vfoo(format, va_list *args) {
  ...
  vbar(format, args);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

GCC can [construct function calls at runtime](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html).

```
foo() {
   void *args = __builtin_apply_args();
   void *ret = __builtin_apply(bar, args, ???);
    __builtin_return(ret);
}
```

`???` is the amount of stack space the arguments take up, which is not necessarily trivial to compute: you will need to understand what the arguments are and architecture-specific details on how they are passed.

Other GCC extensions allow further trickery with macros and inline functions.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - you cannot. Make bar take a `va_list`. If you're willing to lock this down to one specific compiler, you could probably do it with inline assembly, but with standard C or C++ it's not possible.

You should, as a general rule, always implement your vararg functions in terms of `va_list` and then make a wrapper ellipsis function calling the real `va_list` function.

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the 'short answer.' It can be done in C++0x with variadic templates (see answer elsewhere). I'm only going of the question tags though -- the C++ one in particular :)

Comment: @Max Lybbert: Which one of those would C++0x be?

Comment: @phooji: c++0x isn't c++ (yet) - won't do answering a c++-tagged Q with c++0x :)

Comment: @Erik: Aw so little love for 0x!

Comment: @Erik: I know... but do you really want the committee to spend time on the name too? :-p

Comment: @phooji:  my comment referred to the original answer, not your comment.  As in "If you're willing to lock this down to one specific compiler, you could probably do it in inline assembly (or compiler specific extensions)."

Comment: @Max Lybbert: Ah. I was reading too much into your comment. Apologies.

Comment: I wrote my comment while you were writing yours.  If I had seen your comment, I would have made it more clear that I was referring to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

This works in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Format>
void meheer(const Format& format) {
  std::cout << format << std::endl;;
}

template<typename Format, typename Elt, typename ... Args>
void meheer(const Format& format, const Elt & e, const Args&... args) {
  std::cout << format << e;
  meheer(format, args...);
}

template<typename Format, typename ... Args>
void ohai(const Format& format, const Args&... args) {
  meheer(format, args...);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  ohai(1,2,3);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output:**

```
12131
```

Of course, this is C++0x specific, but it works in my not-super-recent version of gcc. See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Variadic_templates

**Update** Added full-length example.