# Rationale on Boost.Preprocessor using macros instead of simple defines?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

For example `BOOST_PP_ITERATE` and `BOOST_PP_ITERATION`, as seen on GMan's answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475046/any-metaprogramming-way-to-generate-overloads-for-various-numbers-of-template-par/5475750#5475750), are preprocessor macros, without any parameters. Is there a reason they're not just simple defines and used as such without `()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, function like macro can be used to prevent unintentional macro
expansion.
For example, assuming that we have the following macro call:

```
BOOST_PP_CAT( BOOST_PP_ITERATION, _DEPTH )
```

and we expect this will be expanded into `BOOST_PP_ITERATION_DEPTH`.
However, if `BOOST_PP_ITERATION` is an object like(non-functional) macro,
it will be expanded to its own definition before the token
`BOOST_PP_ITERATION_DEPTH` is generated by concatenation.

Comment: This seems to be it, bot not only for concatenation, but also to pass these macros around to other `BOOST_PP` macros, like `BOOST_PP_EMPTY` is often used for `BOOST_PP_ENUM(NUM,MYMACRO,BOOST_PP_EMPTY)`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because they perform operations: consequently, their usage should make it clear that you are actually **invoking** something and not just using some constant.

Comment: Okay, that may hold true for `BOOST_PP_ITERATE`, but what about `BOOST_PP_ITERATION`? That's only supposed to be used as your current iteration depth, afaik.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you mentioned `BOOST_PP_ITERATION`. Well I guess the rationale is quite similar: since the result of `BOOST_PP_ITERATION` is variable, it makes sense to make it look like a function returning a value. Plus consistency, of course.

Comment: But now I see that `BOOST_PP_IS_ITERATING` does not use this convention... :-s !