# make_unique does not compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create and use `make_unique` for `std::unique_ptr`, in the same way `std::make_shared` exists for `std::shared_ptr` [described here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared). Herb Sutter [mentions](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/) the possible implementation of `make_unique` that looks like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args )
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

It doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using the following sample program:

```
// testproject.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct A {
  A(int&& n) { std::cout << "rvalue overload, n=" << n << "\n"; }
  A(int& n)  { std::cout << "lvalue overload, n=" << n << "\n"; }
};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&& ...args ) {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>( new T( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> p1 = make_unique<A>(2); // rvalue
  int i = 1;
  std::unique_ptr<A> p2 = make_unique<A>(i); // lvalue
}
```

And the compiler (I'm using VS2010) gives me the following output:

```
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(15): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(16): error C2065: 'Args' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(16): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error : '...'
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>d:\projects\testproject\testproject\testproject.cpp(22): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
```

Also if you replace the `make_unique` implementation to the following

```
template<class T, class U>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(U&& u) {
  return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<U>(u)));
}
```

(which is taken from [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) example), it compiles and works fine.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? It seems to me that VS2010 is having some trouble with `...` in template declaration, and I don't know what can I do about it.

Comment: Variadic Templates are only supported as of the CTP.

Comment: You should note that Herb Sutter's suggestion is not suitable for array types. Stephan T Lavavej posted an improved version in his recent episode of Core C++ that works for arrays, too, like `make_unique<int[]>(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: [here is a link to the `make_unique` that KerrekSB mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13512344/845092)

Comment: If you would like to use variadic templates in visual studio you need the latest updates. My own instructions: http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36204698243/setupcpp11-msvs

Comment: Your make_unique example doesn't compile for me. I get `error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Variadic templates aren't available in the released version of Visual C++ 11. You can, however, simulate the argument expansion with either lots of copy/paste code for different number of parameters, or use the same compiler tricks used in Microsoft's own implementation of "pseudo-variadics". From this comment on Herb Sutter's blog: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/#comment-6428

```
#include <memory> // brings in TEMPLATE macros.

#define _MAKE_UNIQUE(TEMPLATE_LIST, PADDING_LIST, LIST, COMMA, X1, X2, X3, X4)  \
\
template<class T COMMA LIST(_CLASS_TYPE)>    \
inline std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(LIST(_TYPE_REFREF_ARG))    \
{    \
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(LIST(_FORWARD_ARG)));    \
}

_VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_MAKE_UNIQUE, , , , )
#undef _MAKE_UNIQUE
```

Comment: Note: the use of `_[A-Z].*` identifiers is reserved to the implementation (in your case, the VC++ compiler and the Dirkumware STL).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks for pointing that out, I personally don't like to start identifiers with `_`. When I implemented `make_unique()` at work, I expanded the code to 10 parameters by hand (err, copy/paste) and dumped it in a utility namespace to avoid conflicting with a future `std` implementation.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), variadic templates are not supported in Visual C++ 2010 or 2012.

Comment: They are supported in the CTP.

Comment: [VC++ November 2012 CTP can be found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515)