# How to implement make_unique function in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, c++14

My compiler doesn't support make_unique. How to write one?

```
template< class T, class... Args > unique_ptr<T> make_unique( Args&&... args );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to write make_unique() in VS2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12547983/341970)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Copied from [make_unique and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7038357/341970) (the same is given in [Herb Sutter's blog](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/))

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

If you need it in VC2012, see [Is there a way to write make_unique() in VS2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12547983/341970)

---

Nevertheless, if the solution in [sasha.sochka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902439/341970) compiles with your compiler, I would go with that one. That is more elaborate and works with arrays as well.

Comment: Why do the dots go outside the args parentheses?  That's so counterintuitive to me!

Comment: @Apollys If I understand your question correctly: That would expand the arguments to `std::forward`, and not to `T`. (Maybe I misunderstand your question.)

Comment: Likely that is what I was asking, I don't know much about the `...` syntax, only what I have seen in examples.  What seems weird to me is that in the line `std::forward<Args>(args)...` it seems that `args` now somehow means each parameter individually while at the top it meant all of the parameters as a unit.

Comment: @Apollys Yeah, C++ is a weird language, full of such quirks. :(

Comment: This won't work when calling `make_unique` to create an array type like `unsigned char[]` and yields the error message `Allocation of incomplete type`.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Read the answer again: I made it very explicit that this does not work with arrays (hint: the last two sentences).

Answer (score 50):

Version by Stephan T. Lavavej (also known by STL) who originally proposed adding this function to C++14

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace std {
    template<class T> struct _Unique_if {
        typedef unique_ptr<T> _Single_object;
    };

    template<class T> struct _Unique_if<T[]> {
        typedef unique_ptr<T[]> _Unknown_bound;
    };

    template<class T, size_t N> struct _Unique_if<T[N]> {
        typedef void _Known_bound;
    };

    template<class T, class... Args>
        typename _Unique_if<T>::_Single_object
        make_unique(Args&&... args) {
            return unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        }

    template<class T>
        typename _Unique_if<T>::_Unknown_bound
        make_unique(size_t n) {
            typedef typename remove_extent<T>::type U;
            return unique_ptr<T>(new U[n]());
        }

    template<class T, class... Args>
        typename _Unique_if<T>::_Known_bound
        make_unique(Args&&...) = delete;
}
```

EDIT: updated code to the [N3656](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3656.txt) standard revision

Comment: How does the `_Known_bound` struct match when no use of `_Unique_if` specifies a second template argument and there is no default?

Comment: @BenJackson The intent is for there to never be a match for the `_Known_bound` version when `make_unique` is used correctly. If someone tries to use it as `make_unique<T[N]>()` it'll match the `_Known_bound` version and result in an error.

Comment: What's a good way to include this definition in C++ code that may eventually be compiled in an environment where make_unique is available in stdc++?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus I'd suggest #if __cplusplus == 201103L ... #endif (see __cplusplus entry near the end of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html )

Comment: Note that we are not allowed to put things into std:: like this. I'd rather use my own utilities namespace if I had to add `make_unique`.

Comment: you might check for __cplusplus version to avoid problems.