# Proper Destructors / RAII / Something

Tags: c++

Here's a minimal example of a problem that I'm having, and I can't work out how I should solve it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Thing {
};

class App {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> thingVec;
    void add_thing(Thing*);
};

void App::add_thing(Thing* thing) {
    thingVec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Thing>(thing));
}

int main() {
    App app;

    Thing thing;

    app.add_thing(&thing);
}
```

This compiles and runs with no issues, however, upon reaching the end of main, segfaults and spits out:

```
Error in `/path/testapp': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff97118070 ***
```

Any possible help? The reason I want to store (unique) pointers is that Thing will usually be derived.

EDIT:
One working solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Thing {
};

class App {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> thingVec;
    void add_thing(Thing*);
};

void App::add_thing(Thing* thing) {
    thingVec.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Thing>(thing));
}

int main() {
    App app;

    Thing* thing = new Thing;
    app.add_thing(thing);
}
```

But from what I understand, I should be able to avoid using new entirely, and use make_unique? I can't seem to find where make_unique is actually defined though.

EDIT 2:

Is this more appropriate? Is there a less messy looking way to do this? Otherwise, it works well.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Thing {
public:
    int foo = 42;
};

class App {
public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Thing>> thingVec;
    void add_thing(std::unique_ptr<Thing>);
};

void App::add_thing(std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing) {
    thingVec.push_back(std::move(thing));
}

int main() {
    App app;
    app.add_thing(std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing()));

    std::cout << app.thingVec.back()->foo << std::endl;
}
```

Because I may end up with lines like

```
app.thingVex.back()->barVec.back()->blahMap.emplace("flop", std::unique_ptr<Tree>(new Tree));
```

Comment: The std::unique_ptr destroys the object when it goes out of scope. However the pointed to object is already destroyed because it is declared on the stack.

Comment: They "forgot" to specify `make_unique` in C++11. They fixed it in C++14. Until then just write your own `make_unique`, it is [fairly easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11).

Comment: See also: [Guideline: Express a "sink" function using a by-value `unique_ptr` parameter.](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface to `add_thing` is wrong because it takes a "non-owning" raw pointer to a `Thing` and then *assumes* that it can take full ownership of the object passed in by constructing a `unique_ptr` from it.

If you change `add_thing` to take a `unique_ptr<Thing>` by value, then the caller will be prevented from implicitly converting a raw pointer and will no that they need to construct a new `unique_ptr` to a heap allocated thing into the `add_thing` function.

e.g.

```
void App::add_thing(std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing) {
    thingVec.push_back(std::move(thing));
}

int main() {
    App app;    
    app.add_thing(std::make_unique<Thing>());
}
```

(Note that `std::make_unique` is a future feature; `std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing)` works now.)

Comment: An alternative to the `unique_ptr` is passing a `Thing &&` which can then be `move`ed into the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that. I had that originally, but it was rather clunky having to create the unique_ptrs manually beforehand

Comment: @nwp what will two & do?

Comment: @nwp: Which works but does also require `Thing` to be movable.

Comment: @Jagoly A `Test &&` is a temporary value ([rvalue](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_03.html)). When using a value from the stack you will get a compiler error saying it cannot convert an lvalue to an rvalue, thus preventing this kind of error.

Comment: @CharlesBailey True. Honestly I have never had to deal with any `Thing` that is not movable. It probably makes sense to offer both functions.

Comment: @nwp: It might make sense to provide both but as `App` isn't a template function you'd only do this if `Thing` actually was movable. (If `Thing` was an olde C++03 class with a user-defined copy constructor then moving it might not be as efficient as "move" suggests.)

Comment: You can write your own `make_unique`. It is [fairly easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11) and solved enough problems to make it worth it.

Answer (score 6):

`std::unique_ptr` is attempting to delete a stack-allocated `Thing` instance.

Your error is essentially in the lines:

```
 Thing thing;
 app.add_thing(&thing);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass local object to unique_ptr.

Replace

```
Thing thing;
app.add_thing(&thing);
```

with

```
app.add_thing(new Thing);
```

If you want to also edit the object

```
Thing *thing = new Thing;
// thing->some_val = val;
app.add_thing(thing);
```

Make sure not to add the same object twice in the app, as std::unique_ptr take the ownership of pointer pointer would be tried to free more than 1 time.

Comment: @Bathsheba: but even with this solution the interface to `add_thing` is dangerous because it doesn't prevent this sort of client "error" or document in any way that this usage is problematic.

Comment: Ahhh. Ok. The reason I was trying to initialise them before is because I was trying to run some other methods on them before adding them. I suppose I would just have to add them first, and the run the methods on the last element of the vector?

Comment: Yes I should have written "a possible solution", but I'll leave it now as it will invalidate more helpful comments.

Comment: @CharlesBailey You are right, the interface is dangerous and let do the nasty things.

Answer (score 0):

You are transferring the ownership not properly. You might utilize a shared pointer with a custom deleter to the prevent deletion of the referenced variable:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Thing {
};

class App {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Thing>> thingVec;
    void add_thing(std::shared_ptr<Thing>&& thing) {
        thingVec.push_back(std::move(thing));
    }
};


template<typename T>
inline std::shared_ptr<T> make_no_delete(T& value)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(&value, [](void*){});
}


int main() {
    App app;

    Thing thing;

    // Add without transferring ownership:
    app.add_thing(make_no_delete(thing));
    // Add and transfer ownership:
    app.add_thing(std::make_shared<Thing>());
}
```