# Smart pointers and parameter list allocation rules

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

[An MSDN page about smart pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx) includes a promoted warning about creating smart pointers in parameter lists:

> Always create smart pointers on a separate line of code, never in a parameter list, so that a subtle resource leak won’t occur due to certain parameter list allocation rules.

What are the parameter list allocation rules that it is referring to? Under what circumstances can the resource leak occur?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's referring to the possibility of evaluating parameters in a different order, e.g.

```
func(unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass), a(), b());
```

if the order of evaluation is: `a()`, `MyClass()`, `b()`, then `unique_ptr` is constructed, it might happen that `b()` throws and memory will be leaked.

A safeguard (that has been added in C++14 and it's also more efficient) is to use `make_unique` (assuming MSVC and according to your compiler version, you might have to define one yourself or [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17903225/1938163)). The same applies to `shared_ptr`.

Take a look [at the notes for std::make_shared here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), too:

> Moreover, code such as `f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` can
>   cause a memory leak if `g` throws an exception because `g()` may be called
>   after `new int(42)` and before the constructor of `shared_ptr<int>`. This
>   doesn't occur in `f(std::make_shared<int>(42), g())`, since two function
>   calls are never interleaved.

Comment: Since the OP appears to be using VS, I think `make_unique` is already supported in VS2013.

Comment: Thanks, edited for clarity. VS2012 might be a problem since it doesn't support variadic templates, I provided a fallback link with the issue. (or OP might try CTP, I believe update 2 should work)

Comment: Anyway, there are additional reasons to prefer `allocate_shared` and `make_shared` to doing that manually: Efficiency.

Comment: @Deduplicator sure, I didn't write "*that's the reason you should use X*" because it also provides other benefits (and also readability in my opinion, but that might be argued)

Comment: A minor nit-pick: I would be extremely astounded if `make_unique` was any more or less efficient than calling `std::unique_ptr`s ctor yourself directly.

Comment: I did have some trouble understanding the answer but are you saying the code may execute the inner bracket of shared_ptr constructor and then execute g() before it has executed the shared_ptr constructor?  This seems quite an odd sequence for the compiler to choose.  Why would the standard allow it?  Does make_shared get around this issue?

Comment: @Robinson Take a look at 5.2.2.8 and integrate it with [herb's Q&A](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/)

Comment: `make_unique` has nothing to do with efficiency, it's entirely to do with reducing redundancy (no specifying the type twice) and to enable better sequencing when used in a parameter list. `make_shared`, on the other hand, does prevent a duplicate allocation -- but this is also available in C++11. It might be worth clarifying, since the current wording sounds as though `make_shared` is C++14 as well -- which is incorrect

Answer (score 5):

If you do this:

```
func(shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo), shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar));
```

And the signature is:

```
void func(shared_ptr<Foo>, shared_ptr<Bar>);
```

What will happen if one of the constructors throws?  It may happen that `new` has been called once successfully and then the other one fails (you don't know which one will get called first).  If that happens, one of the objects could be leaked, because it was never held by a resource manager.

You can read more here: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/056.htm

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if you have function that takes several arguments:

```
void func( const std::shared_ptr< MyFirstClass >& ptr, const MySecondClass& ref );
```

and you call this function like this:

```
func( std::shared_ptr< MyFirstClass >( new MyFirstClass ), MySecondClass() );
```

the compiler is free to emit code that executes the expressions in the argument list in any order it likes. Some of these orders can be problematic. For instance, imagine that the compiler decides to emit code that first executes

```
new MyFirstClass
```

and then

```
MySecondClass()
```

and finally the c'tor of std::shared_ptr< MyFirstClass > (passing it the address of the instance of MyFirstClass that was allocated on the free store in the first step).

So far so good. But if the second step throws an exception, then the shared_ptr never gets constructed, and your free store allocated MyFirstClass-instance is forever lost.