# Passing a unique_ptr reference to boost::bind?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

I'm on CentOS 6.6 (gcc 4.4.7) and developing with Boost.Asio (1.41). I'd like io_service to call member function `run()` in manger object `m` when it starts. The code I'm trying to compile looks like:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

boost::asio::io_service io;
std::unique_ptr<manager> m;
m = std::make_unique<manager>;
io.post(boost::bind(&manager::run, &m));
```

gcc pitches a fit on the `boost::bind` statement, which includes:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:40: error: pointer to
member type ‘void (manager::)()’ incompatible with object type
‘std::unique_ptr<manager, std::default_delete<manager> >’
```

What do I want to be doing here?

The manager object will only know about timers; a separate object that knows about io_service will get added to its constructor later. But the idea is that `manager::run()` will create an initial set of timers to bootstrap the system.

Clarification:

My thinking here is that the outer block of code manages the lifetime of `m` and that the next statement will be `io.run()`. The outer code will destroy `m` when `io.run()` returns. Hence, passing a raw reference for `m` to `io` is appropriate. But I'm a modern C++ novice and could be way off base here.

Comment: You don't pass a reference of any kind to `bind` -- you pass a regular pointer to a unique pointer. But unique pointers must be unique, and with your code, when the `post` returns, there are two -- one in the posted `bind` and one in `m`. That obviously can't be right. Perhaps you want `boost::bind (&manager::run, std::move(m))`?

Comment: `boost::bind` doesn't know how to unwrap a `unique_ptr`, you need pass it either a `manager *` (`m.get()`) or a `manager` instance (`*m`) (the second one makes a copy of the object `m` points to). And I find it difficult to believe you're using gcc4.4.7; that compiler doesn't even understand `-std=c++11`, let alone `std::make_unique`, a C++14 addition.

Comment: gcc 4.4.7 has `-std=gnu++0x`, and for `make_unique` I snagged [STL's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need C++-14 and [generalized lambda capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640393/move-capture-in-lambda/20669290#20669290) to make this work -- you'd need to move the unique pointer into the lambda. Instead, just use a `shared_ptr`, which `std::bind` understands natively:

```
std::shared_ptr<manager> m;
m = std::make_shared<manager>();
io.post(std::bind(&manager::run, std::move(m)));
```

The `std::move` is optional but ensures that `m` doesn't keep the manager around when it's not wanted.

Comment: I feel dirty doing this, at least with my current understanding of the implications of unique vs. shared pointers. `io` won't be responsible for the lifecycle of `m`. The way the program is headed, `m` will get cleaned up after `io.run()` (which will come shortly after `io.post()`) returns. Does `make_shared()` give the reader the wrong idea?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus The `m` variable will get cleaned up, but the `bind` will capture the shared pointer by value, keeping the manager around as long as the `bind` stays around, which it must until its execution completes.

Comment: Is it Bad and Wrong to keep `m` as a `unique_ptr` and change the bind statement to: `boost::bind(&manager::run, m.get())`?

Comment: @AndreasYankopolus Yes, because then the manager can be deleted too soon (as soon as `m` goes out of scope). You need the `bind` to keep the manager alive and that requires it to capture something, by value, that keeps the manager around.