# How to call class destructor / constructor

Tags: c++, class

Say I have two classes like so:

controller.hpp (included by controller.cpp)

```
#include "testing.hpp"
class controller
{
    public:
        testing _testing;  // call constructor
}
```

testing.hpp

```
class testing
{
    public:
        testing();
        ~testing();
}
```

How do I call the destructor of `testing` and re-construct it from controller.cpp?  Thank you.

Comment: `_testing = testing();`

Comment: You don't need to. It happens automatically when an instance of the `controller` class is created! If you want to call something other than the default constructor, use a [member initialization list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) in the `controller` class's constructor.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thank you.  That gives me a whole bunch of errors about Boost deleted function on my atomic variables.  What about calling `testing _testing;` again?

Comment: @xinthose That's a data member declaration. Look for the fix for your errors. You probably need a move constructor.

Comment: @LogicStuff OK.  How would I use a move constructor in this case?  I use atomic bools like so in the `testing` class: `boost::atomic <bool> atomic_var {false};`  Would it be `testing _testing1;`, `_testing = std::move(testing1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code a `controller` owns *a* `testing`. The implication to anyone reading the code is that it *is the same* `testing` for the lifetime of the `controller`. This is certainly also how C++ see it - it will construct *the* `testing` during construction of a `controller` and destroy *the* `testing` when the `controller` is destroyed.

Two possible solutions:

1. Instead of trying to *replace* `testing`, *reset* it. This is what @LogicStuff was talking about in his comment on your question. `_testing = testing();` constructs a new `testing` and then copies its state to the existing instance, making the exisiting instance look like a new one. You could (should?) make this explicit by giving `testing` a `Reset` method (whose implementation should typically be that assignment  `*this = testing();` rather than a hand-coded resetting of each member variable.) - Do this **only** if resetting a `testing` makes business sense.
2. If *resetting* `testing` doesn't make sense on a business level, and you are in fact wanting to *replace* it, then have `controller` own a `std::unique_ptr<testing>` instead. Then you can `reset` or `swap` a newly constructed instance in whenever you need to and still be sure that destructors will be called automatically.

Comment: I agree.  Thank you.  How would the code look?  `std::unique_ptr <testing> _testing (new testing);`?

Comment: Nvm; `std::unique_ptr <testing> _testing` compiles.  Variables and functions are accessived via `->` and not `.` anymore.  Now I need to figure out how to use this with `boost::thread thr (boost::bind(&testing::func1, &_testing));`

Comment: Turns out I need to use a `shared_ptr` for that operation (safer than unique_ptr): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28823025/4056146.  I'm using Boost 1.55 (Debian 8 repo), which doesn't have `unique_ptr` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't explicitly call the destructor.  It is call automatically when the object is destroyed.  When an object is created on the stack, the destructor is called automatically when the object goes out of scope.  When an object is created on the heap (by new'ing it), the destructor is called automatically when delete is called on the object.

Comment: There is a case when destructors are called explicitly.

Comment: Good point, Sergey.  Thanks for the comment.  I made an edit to reflect your comment.  One does not usually call the destructor.  Like you mentioned, the destructor can be called.  The question xinthose asked is not clear why the destructor would need to be called explicitly.  That's why I answered the way I did.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you totally misunderstand the idea of default constructors. The main idea is that you almost never call default constructor explicitly (absent placement new). Ditto for destructors. So in your case, `testing` constructor will be called automatically whenever `controller` object is created, and it it's destructor will be called whenever `controller` object is destroyed.

Comment: Thank you.  I do not want to call the destructor on `controller` because it runs my main code.  So I will need to initialize the `testing` object outside of the header file I think.