# Lazy initialization of unique_ptr in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm developing c++ project in c++11 (gcc 4.8.2). Recently I found `unique_ptr` is useful for me. Unfortunately I can't use the `std::make_unique` function in my environment. So I tried lazy initialization of `unique_ptr` by using `std::move`.

Actually, the below code works, I don't have confidence in myself. Could you give any comments on better ways to initialize a `unique_ptr`? I think my initialization is a little redundant.

```
 class AppData {
     public:
         AppData(int id):_id(id){};

         int _id;
         void print() { std::cout << "id is " << _id << std::endl; };
 };

 class Test {
     public:
         Test(){};
         ~Test(){};
         void test();

         std::unique_ptr<AppData> p_data;
 };

 void Test::test() {
     // I am concerned with this part
     std::unique_ptr<AppData> p(new AppData(3));
     p_data = std::move(p);
     p_data->print();
 }

 int main() {
     Test t;
     t.test();

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `auto p = std::make_unique<AppData>(3);`

Comment: You chose a very bad name for your function, as it is easily mistaken with the constructor. Do you plan to initialize the unique_ptr at construction time? Or later?

Comment: What about this is "lazy"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could more easily do

```
p_data.reset(new AppData(3));
```

rather than going through the extra step of creating a new variable just to move from it.  `reset` will release ownership of the owned object (if any) and free it, then take ownership of the argument.

But `make_unique` [is very easy to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11)

To be clear, it would make your `Test::test` function:

```
void Test::test() {
    p_data.reset(new AppData(3));
    p_data->print();
}
```

Comment: GREAT! Thanks for your elegant code. I'd love to use C++14.