# What's the reasoning behind std::unique_ptr<T>'s constructor from T* being explicit?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, explicit-constructor

As `std::unique_ptr` provides a handy way to avoid memory leaks and ensure exception safety, it is sensible to pass them around rather than raw pointers. Thus, one may want (member) functions with a signature like

```
std::unique_ptr<some_type> foo(some data);
```

Unfortunately, when implementing such a function, one cannot simply

```
std::unique_ptr<some_type> foo(some data)
{
  return { new some_type(data) };                  // error
}
```

but must instead

```
std::unique_ptr<some_type> foo(some data)
{
  return std::move( std::unique_ptr<some_type>( new some_type(data) ) );   // awkward
}
```

because the constructor `unique_ptr::unique_ptr(pointer)` is `explicit`. What is the reasoning behind this constructor being `explicit`?

One motivation to make constructors `explicit` is to guard against unintended implicit type conversion. However, as `unique_ptr` cannot be passed by value, this should not really be a problem, should it?

Comment: You could have a `void foo(unique_ptr<T>);` and call it via `int i = 42; foo(&i);`

Comment: In C++14 you can `return std::make_unique<some_type>(data);`

Comment: `return std::make_unique<some_type>(data);`. Unfortunately `make_unique` was "forgotten" in c++11, but c++14 fixed that. You can also [write your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11) `make_unique` in c++11.

Comment: And you don't need to explicitly `std::move` the temporary in C++11.

Comment: `auto_ptr` already had the explicit ownership-taking ctor.

Comment: What are you smoking? unique_ptr can be easily passed by value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`unique_ptr` takes ownership of passed pointer. Taking ownership should be explicit - you don't want some pointer to 'magically' become owned (and deleted) by some class (that was one of issues with deprecated `std::auto_ptr`).

for example:

```
void fun(std::unique_ptr<X> a) { .... }
X x;
fun(&x); // BOOM, deleting object on stack, fortunately it does not compile
fun(std::unique_ptr<X>(&x)); // compiles, but it's explicit and error is clearly visible
```

please note, that `std::move` is not required in `return` statement (special language exception - local variables as `return` arguments can be treated as 'moved').

Also - in C++14 you can use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) to make it less awkward:

```
return std::make_unique<some_data>(some_data_argument1, arg2);
```

(it can be also easily added to C++11 - read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11?lq=1))

Comment: Just wanted to note that `std::make_unique` was available in some compilers before C++14, MSVC12 being one example.

Answer (score 5):

Arguments taking unique ptr should not silently take ownership of pointers.

Thus ctor is explicit.

To return, try `make_unique<foo>(?)` instead of `{new foo(?)}`.