# Can I make the constructor of a derived class constexpr if the base class constructor is not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, constexpr

I am trying to compile an example from "Design Patterns" and I am facing the following problem:

I have a base class MapSite:

```
class MapSite{
public:
    MapSite();
    virtual ~MapSite(); 
    virtual void Enter() = 0;
};
```

and a derived class Room:

```
class Room : public MapSite final{

private:
    unsigned int room_number;

public:
    Room(unsigned int rn) : room_number(rn) {};

    virtual void Enter() override;
};
```

From another class I want to call the function

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Room> MakeRoom(unsigned int n) {return make_unique<Room(n)>();}
```

When I do so I get the following error:

```
error: temporary of non-literal type ‘Room’ in a constant expression
  virtual std::unique_ptr<Room> MakeRoom(unsigned int n) {return unique::make_unique<Room(n)>();}
```

So I thought the problem may be that the constructor has to be `constexpr` in order to call the constructor of Room from another function, but setting the constructor to:

```
constexpr Room(unsigned int rn) : room_number(rn) {};
```

will produce this error:

```
error: call to non-constexpr function ‘MapSite::MapSite()’
  constexpr Room(unsigned int rn) : room_number(rn) {};
```

**My basic question is whether I can make a derived class constructor constexpr, even if the base class constructor is not. Or maybe if there is a much better concept to solve this problem.**

PS: make_unique is a c++14 feature which I emulated from here [How to implement make_unique function in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11) for c++11, which I am compiling with

Comment: Ask yourself: what is it about that code that is even trying to use `Room` in a constant expression and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can i make the constructor of a derived class contexpr if the base class constructor is not constexpr?

No, you can not.

A constexpr function can not call non-constexpr functions. A constructor must call all sub-object (including the base-subobjects) constructors. Therefore all sub-object constructors must be constexpr or else the complete object constructor may not be constexpr.

That said, your original problem is separate, and is covered by NathanOliver's answer.

Answer (score 10):

The issue here is not that `Room` needs a `constexpr` constructor but you are passing a value to a template that expects a type.  in

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Room> MakeRoom(unsigned int n) {return make_unique<Room(n)>();}
```

the `Room(n)` part tries to construct a `Room` and use it as a template parameter for `make_unique`.  This is not what you want to do.  `make_unique` expects a type as it constructs a `std::unique_ptr` of that type from the parameters you pass to it.  If you want to construct a `Room` with `n` then you use

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<Room> MakeRoom(unsigned int n) {return make_unique<Room>(n);}
```