# unique_ptr error cant apply ->

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I am learning about smart pointers and when trying to compile the following "stupid" code I get an error.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    std::string myString="dumm";
};

int main()
{

    std::unique_ptr<Test> test(new Test());
    std::cout<<test->myString<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to see, whether this works but I get :"Applying -> to std::unique_ptr instead of a pointer", which seems weird.

I am using c++ 11

Eit: The error is now fixed and I cancompile the above code. However, CLion still gives me "Cant apply -> to std::uniq_ptr"-stuff, which seems to be an error with the IDE

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get `error: 'class Test' has no member named 'dumm'`.

Comment: Sry, that was a typo. Got the same error message anyways. Edited the code above

Comment: You should `#include <string>` to use `std::string`, and `myString` should be made public in order to access it from outside the `Test` class.

Comment: Once I make a few modifications to eliminate completely different errors I am unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/CGBV0Q

Comment: What is the error you see? You should post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a [class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) the default visibility is [private](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) which makes the `myString` field invisible to the `test` object. Make it `public`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Test {
public:
    std::string myString = "dumm";
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test> test(new Test());
    std::cout << test->myString;
}
```

Prefer [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) to direct use of `new` if compiling for C++14 and later:

```
std::unique_ptr<Test> test = std::make_unique<Test>();
```

This function is not available in the C++11 standard which is what you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Coming from java and member variables are protected by default (If I am not mistaken). Stupid error by me but thanks anyways

Comment: `Prefer std::make_unique to direct use of new:` You should probably mention that `std::make_unique` is not in the C++11 standard that CheckersGuy uses. That said, it's trivial to implement your own `make_unique`.

Comment: @CheckersGuy, Java's default access level for members is package-private.

Comment: @user Not entirely trivial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11