# Whether to use class instances or std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a map which stores attacks for different ports. Now I am confused as for how to store attack details as the value. Also, there can be multiple attacks for one port.

AttackDetails is a structure containing various details of each attack.

Now I have two approaches for the map:

```
std::map <int, std::list<AttackDetails>>
std::map <int, std::list<<std::shared_ptr<AttackDetails>>>
```

There won't be much insertion or deletion but there will be a lot of searchings for ports in the map. Kindly tell me if there is any major performance issue in either of these or any better solution to it?

I need to access the list while deleting the attack details where I will need to traverse through the list and find similar attack id and stop that particular attack.

Comment: Don't look at the smart pointers as simple self-deleting pointers. Instead see them from an *ownership* point of view. Is `AttackDetails` a resource that can only have a single owner (`std::unique_ptr`)? Can the ownership be shared (`std::shared_ptr`)? Or is ownership semantics irrelevant (plain objects or non-owning pointers)?

Comment: Also, the default container should almost always be `std::vector`. What is the reason you picked `std::list`?

Comment: Rather than a `map` of `list`s (or even better, `vector`s), I suggest a `multimap`.

Comment: Is more than one entity responsible for deleting `AttackDetails` objects? Or do they die when they are removed from the map?

Comment: Lastly, remember that `std::map` (and `std::multimap`) is *ordered* by the key. Do you need it to be ordered? If not, then I suggest you use the unordered variants instead.

Comment: If there will be little modifications but a lot of searching, `std::list` is likely to be the worst performing data structure. Use `std::set` or sorted `std::vector`.

Comment: @Fureeish massive searching is done for port only not for the values in map.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need the list of values to be stored according the time of insertion so i can process the attacks accordingly.

Comment: I do not understand what `shared_ptr` has to do with searching performance at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have used list as I am going to push the attack details in it and there won't be a lot of attacks and i don't need vector access. If i need access of details i need to do searching inside the attack details to find the attack I need to stop.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Excess indirection kills cache performance. Like, _kills it_. Then again, the OP already has practically none of that thanks to the map and the list.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I did not state the issue correctly. I need to search in values for when I need to stop a particular attack. Travershing through the list would be needed which will access elements of attack details but there will not be much of insertion or deletion I repeat.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I know that. I just don't understand why `shared_ptr` is even being considered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you seem to just need the `AttackDetails` itself**, not just ones whose lifetimes are managed with RAII semantics, I think that

```
std::map<int, std::list<AttackDetails>>
```

would be more preferable than `std::map<int, std::list<<std::shared_ptr<AttackDetails>>>`.

Similar concepts are stated in [**R.30**](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#r30-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics) of *C++ Core Guidelines* as follows.
Although this is not the exactly same situation with the current problem, but this point of view should be shared with us:

> **R.30: Take smart pointers as parameters only to explicitly express lifetime semantics**
>
> **Reason** Accepting a smart pointer to a widget is wrong if the function just needs the widget itself. It should be able to accept any widget object, not just ones whose lifetimes are managed by a particular kind of smart pointer. A function that does not manipulate lifetime should take raw pointers or references instead.

---

**...any better solution to it?**

- Use `std::unordered_map` if you do not need to sort the elements by key.
- Elements of `std::list` are scattered in memory. Hence it's access operations usually cause cache misses and would show poor performance. Even if erasing any single element of them by `std::list::erase` has the complexity O(1), the access performance is much slower and sometimes makes sense to use other STL containers. I recommend you to test the performance and compare the results between `std::list`, `std::vector` and `std::deque`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need *shared ownership* of an `AttackDetails` instance? If not, then you shouldn't use `std::shared_ptr`.

If you want to optimize searching performance, then consider using a hash data structure such as `unordered_map` (or a faster third-party solution), as that will bring down your complexity from `O(log N)` to `O(1)`.

Comment: There won't be a lot of entries in map and i think performance difference is not that much in unordered and ordered map for even a few hundreds of entries. I do not need shared ownership but I don't have support of C++14

Comment: I'm not clear on why you mentioned C++14. Which part of this answer requires it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `std::AttackDetails`.

Comment: I think unique_ptr requires C++14 support? Sorry if I know wrong about this.

Comment: @ArchitJ no, C++11. You're probably thinking of `std::make_unique`, but that can easily be [implemented in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902405/how-to-implement-make-unique-function-in-c11) as well.

Comment: @ArchitJ Just [look it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), man!