A property of Python class returns an empty numpy array with pybind11
I adopted a project that was abandoned by it's original creator on GH: pybind11 bindings for whispercpp. I had to update Python version from 3.8 to 3.11.8 in CI and discovered that some of the test cases are failing.
Specifically the ones where wav data is read from a file with C++ and then accessed with a property of WavFileWrapper class. The project uses pybind11 to create interfaces for C++ code in Python.
The relevant pieces of code are:
in whispercpp/src/whispercpp/api_cpp2py_export.h
namespace whisper {
// std::make_unique for C++11
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902439/8643197
template <class T> struct _Unique_if {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> _Single_object;
};

template <class T> struct _Unique_if<T[]> {
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T[]> _Unknown_bound;
};

template <class T, size_t N> struct _Unique_if<T[N]> {
    typedef void _Known_bound;
};

template <class T, class... Args>
typename _Unique_if<T>::_Single_object make_unique(Args &&...args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <class T>
typename _Unique_if<T>::_Unknown_bound make_unique(size_t n) {
    typedef typename std::remove_extent<T>::type U;
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new U[n]());
}

template <class T, class... Args>
typename _Unique_if<T>::_Known_bound make_unique(Args &&...) = delete;

// Some black magic to make zero-copy numpy array
// See https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1042#issuecomment-642215028
template <typename Sequence>
inline py::array_t<typename Sequence::value_type> as_pyarray(Sequence &&seq) {
    auto size = seq.size();
    auto data = seq.data();
    std::unique_ptr<Sequence> seq_ptr =
        whisper::make_unique<Sequence>(std::move(seq));
    auto capsule = py::capsule(seq_ptr.get(), [](void *p) {
        std::unique_ptr<Sequence>(reinterpret_cast<Sequence *>(p));
    });
    seq_ptr.release();
    return py::array(size, data, capsule);
}
} // namespace whisper

struct WavFileWrapper {
    py::array_t<float> mono;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> stereo;

    WavFileWrapper(std::vector<float> *mono,
                   std::vector<std::vector<float>> *stereo)
        : mono(whisper::as_pyarray(std::move(*mono))), stereo(*stereo){};

    static WavFileWrapper load_wav_file(const char *filename);
};

in whispercpp/src/whispercpp/api_cpp2py_export.cpp
WavFileWrapper WavFileWrapper::load_wav_file(const char *filename) {
    std::vector<float> pcmf32;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> pcmf32s;
    if (!::read_wav(filename, pcmf32, pcmf32s, false)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load wav file");
    }
    return WavFileWrapper(&pcmf32, &pcmf32s);
}
...
    m.def("load_wav_file", &WavFileWrapper::load_wav_file, "filename"_a,
          py::return_value_policy::reference);

    py::class_<WavFileWrapper>(m, "Wavfile",
                               "A light wrapper for the processed wav file.")
        .def_property_readonly(
            "stereo", [](WavFileWrapper &self) { return self.stereo; },
            py::return_value_policy::reference)
        .def_property_readonly(
            "mono", [](WavFileWrapper &self) { return self.mono; },
            py::return_value_policy::reference);

I checked with print statements and the underlying WAV file read function works correctly. But in Python code, the property mono only returns zero array.
I found a workaround - returning std::vector<float> pcmf32 directly (so only mono sound) works, the array has sounds samples inside of it this way.
If necessary, here is the repository in question with workaround commit:
https://github.com/AIWintermuteAI/whispercpp/commit/cc9d09889dd1adf42e1008692b1106122c7d19b1#diff-c1e9ecf4e144bd332e8d271fff939f6741ed30165e666237d69277b984a398ed .
Edit: Update from 3.8 to 3.9 also causes the described issue.

What's the question? Seems like you're just announcing some workaround with a link to an external resource --- not sure why it was upvoted in the first place. A proper [mcve] is needed to make this a good question. IMHO you should be able to provide a dummy implementation of read_wav that just generates some fake data but otherwise mimics the third party library API, and make the MCVE standalone.

Passing around pointers instead of references seems a bit sketchy. And it's really odd to have a py::array_t for mono and vector of vectors for stereo.... your proposed work-around sounds sensible, but you really should make that into a self-answer. Remember this is a Q&A site, not a blog or a help-desk. Both question and answers should be complete and self-contained, problems should be easily reproducible.

I only mentioned a workaround I came up with because it might have provided some clue of where it went wrong in the first place. I admit minimal reproducible example would be nice, but since it involves pybind11 I'd need to write a lot of boilerplate code, so I thought just linking the repository might work better.

The thing that puzzles me is why would it stop working when upgrading from Python 3.8 to 3.9.

Hard to say without seeing the implementation of whisper::as_pyarray (don't wanna go hunting for it). In your question you say "3.8 to 3.11.8" but now you say even "3.8 to 3.9" makes a difference. The more you can narrow it, the better, make sure the question contains that info. And just to make sure -- this is still using the same version of pybind11? Which version? Same compiler and everything else? What platform? (I would still suggest that you post your workaround as an answer -- it does seem like a valid approach, as opposed to what the library seems to do).

Thanks for suggestions! I made the edits. Yes, pybind11 version is the same. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/commit/f33f6afb same compiler and everything else. I first observed the issue in GH Actions, where I simply changed Python version used for Action. Then I reproduced locally as well.

Cool, that already makes it much better. Just clarify which compiler and its version, and which C++ standard you're compiling it for. (Again, [edit] the question, and no need to highlight it as an explicit edit -- just make the main text contain all the relevant info). The need to provide make_unique suggests C++11 at best, which is rather ancient.
