# C syntax to create function foo(...)

Tags: c, linux, syntax, printf

Sorry for the simple question, but how could I create the C-function with undefined number of parameters such as

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... ).
```

I would like to create function to use it as wrapper for printk:

```
void my_printk( const char * format, ...)
{
    printk("my log:");
    printk(format, ...);
    printk("\n");
}
```

Thanks

Comment: printk is function for log from kernel - I use it in character device driver

Comment: Well, you can create your own function with variable arguments, but AFAIK you can't pass them to another function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [To invoke a variadic function with unamed arguments of another variadic function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383642/to-invoke-a-variadic-function-with-unamed-arguments-of-another-variadic-function)

Comment: AndreyT, printk is a function that prints messages and is used in the C Programming Language exclusively for the Linux Kernel.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. Have a look here: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

> ```
> int f(int, ... );
>
> int f(int, ... ) {
>         .
>         .
>         .
> }
>
> int g() {
>         f(1,2,3);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You have to convert the args to a va_list before you can pass it to another function. Then you can pass it to the 'v' version of the function.

So you can do:

```
void my_printk( const char * format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    printk("my log:");
    vprintk(format, ap);
    printk("\n");
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Most of the time, any function like this will provide a 'v' version, and yours should too:

```
void my_vprintk( const char * format, va_list ap)
{
    printk("my log:");
    vprintk(format, ap);
    printk("\n");
}

void my_printk( const char * format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    my_vprintk(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}
```