# Is it possible using log4cplus in C code?

Tags: c, log4cplus

I have searched the web and log4cplus documentation for the question on how to use the [log4cplus](http://sourceforge.net/p/log4cplus/wiki/Home/) library in a pure C code and haven't found a clear answer.
Is it possible?

Comment: The only way is to make a C++ library which exports the functionality of log4cplus as functions callable by C.

Comment: I tried doing something like that but I was stuck when trying to pass a variable number of arguments to the log function. It seems [impossible](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html). Another [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

log4cplus has limited C API since log4cplus 1.1.0-RC1. Branches 1.1.x and 1.2.x have the same API. Master, which will eventually become 2.0.x, has slightly modified and extended C API. In either case, they support printf-style formatted output. See [`clogger.h`](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/blob/1.1.x/include/log4cplus/clogger.h) on 1.1.x branch or look at the same file on master, depending on which version of the library you are using.

<sub>The intention of this API is to provide logging support for applications with mixed C and C++ code. Its intention is not to provide 1:1 translation to C for the whole log4cplus.</sub>