# How to use an undefined number of parameters in a function?

Tags: c

I want to develop a basic function which includes the printf() one. Having troubles with the arguments of the function

I'm trying to develop a basic function similar to this one:

```
basi_fun(const char* CMD, val1, val2, val3)
{
     fun1();
     printf(CMD,val1,val2?,...);
     fun2();
}
```

The problem is related to the fact that I don't know how `printf()` is able to understand the number and type of variable needed. In a similar way I don't know how to allow my `basic_fun()` to ask for a variable number and type of parameter. 
By looking in the stdio.h header I understood that the function `printf()` is based on `vfprintf(...)`:

```
extern int  vfprintf(FILE *__stream, const char *__fmt, va_list __ap);
```

and by means of `__ap` is able to accept a variable number of variables which number and types is defined by the number and type of `%d`,`%c`,etc inside the `__fmt` char array.
After this I tried to develop something similar to this:

```
basi_fun(const char *__fmt, va_list __ap)
{
     fun1();
     printf(__fmt, __ap);
     fun2();
}
```

Actually it still do not work. What am I missing? Also an indication on where to learn the __ap could be useful.

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c help?

Comment: I edit the question. You were both really fast and helpfull to me. I maneged to solve my problem in just 5 min thanks to you! I know it was a very stupid question but i was stack.