# Pass arguments from one function to another (without templates) - C++

Tags: c++, function

## Question

Is there a way to pass arguments from a *"sender"* function to a *"receiver"* function in C++?

---

## Expectation/ Theory

```
void print(const char character) { std::putchar(character); }
void print(char message[], unsigned length) {
    for (unsigned iterator = 0u; iterator ^ length; iterator += 1)
        print(*(message + iterator));
}

void println(...) { print(...); print('\n'); std::fflush(stdout); }
```

In this example:
• `println` is the *"sender"* function and
• `print` is the *"receiver"* function.

The `print` function is to accept all arguments of the `println` function as denoted by the example `...` syntax.

---

## Context

I do know of template functions in C++ and how it can rectify the former example to be

```
void print(const char);
void print(char[], unsigned); // They’ve been defined before already…

template <typename... types>
void println(types... arguments) { print(arguments...); print('\n'); std::fflush(stdout); }
```

**But I want to see if there is another approach** to this problem — without fairly recent **C++**-only features *i.e.: how was this problem solved in C?*

I code in a ***C-style** manner (using C features over C++ features)* in **C++** because I want to know how to build C++ features personally.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c) seems similar

Comment: Very similar... There are a few approaches to the problem I could try. I'll stick around longer to see if there could be *maybe* any more answers... Otherwise I'll close the question, then

Comment: "I want to know how to build C++ features personally" -> A new function is instantiated from the template every time you call `println` with a different set of `types...`. You could just literally do that (Create two `println` overloads as well)

Comment: @Artyer Yea but what if there are more than just a *few* `print` functions to have a `println` variation for.

Answer (score 1):

> how was this problem solved in C?

In C use macros. A function macro with only `...` and pass the arguments to the function:

```
#define println(...)  do { \
        print(__VA_ARGS__); \
        print('\n'); \
        std::fflush(stdout); \
} while(0)
```

There is one limitation - calling such function macro without any arguments is not allowed according to ISO C standard.

It's common **in C** to use a [gcc extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) of applying `##` preprocessor operator to `__VA_ARGS__` and pass additional parameters to the `print` function, like `__func__` or `__LINE__` or `__FILE__` for debugging purposes. Like ex. [here](https://github.com/intel/edison-u-boot/blob/master/include/test/ut.h#L53) or [here](https://spdk.io/doc/log_8h.html) or [here](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/blob/master/src/wazuh_modules/wm_keyrequest.c#L26) (just a few first results from a short google search).

```
#define println(str, ...)  do { \
        print("%s:%d: " str "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
        fflush(stdout); \
} while(0)
```

Comment: **Hmm, what if I don't want to globally define the `println` macro?** Here's an impractical example: I create a `print` function in a local namespace and want it to have a `printf` and `println` variation that rely on the `print` function, but defining `printf` as a macro completely overrides the native `printf` function provided by the C standard library.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does it mean to "globally define"? How can you define "not globally"? Didn't you answer yourself? In C there are no namespaces and sometimes names clash. Just pick a unique name.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm using C++ so there are `namespace` scopes that allow variables and functions to be defined within the namespace alone