# gcc: forwarding variadic function call

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

Is there any way to call a variadic function from another one?

I know that if I want to forward a variadic call, I can use a function that accepts `va_list` parameters.

For example, If I declare `my_printf` I can call `vfprintf` inside.

Another way would be to use macros:

```c
#define my_printf(a, ...) fprintf(a, __VA_ARGS__)
```

but is there a way to "create" a variadic call without being forced to use `va_list` parameters?

In other words: is there any way (standard or not, using gcc extensions, etc.) that `my_printf` can call `fprintf` directly and not `vfprintf`?

Comment: The C standard does not provide any facility for this.

Comment: The best solution is to avoid anything variadic in the first place. It's a horrible and dangerous API.

Comment: Can you describe what real world problem you are attempting to solve using this method?  Also, have you seen [this question/many answers]?   I will vote to close this question, not because it isn't a good question, but because it has been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c).  If you can explain how your request distinguishes itself from the linked post, please do, and If indeed you can do that, I will remove the close vote.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to call a variadic function from another one?

Yes, use `va_list`. It's **the way** to call another variadic function, standardized and supported everywhere. When providing a variadic function from your library, make sure you provide `va_list` version as well. Do not use other options, unless you definitely have to.

> is there any way (standard

No.

Well, there is super old [POSIX varargs.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/varargs.h.html).

> using gcc extensions

There are some builtin functions: [__builtin_va_arg_pack() stuff](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html) and `__builtin_apply()` stuff.

> etc.)

Write some assembly to forward the arguments.

There are [FFI libraries](https://github.com/libffi/libffi) available.