# forward args of variadic function in C

Tags: c

I want to forward args of variadic function, I have already find the some topic.

- [Forward an invocation of a variadic function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150543/forward-an-invocation-of-a-variadic-function-in-c)

When I start to practice, I found a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void fun1(const char *msg, ...) // try to forward printf
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, msg);
    vprintf(msg, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}

void fun2(const char *msg, ...) // try to forward fun1
{
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, msg);
    fun1(msg, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}

int main()
{
    fun1("this is int %d, float %f\n", 1, 2.3);
    fun2("this is int %d, float %f\n", 1, 2.3);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile code with `gcc main.c` and the output shown that

```
this is int 1, float 2.300000
this is int 6684168, float 2.300000
```

I can not understand why the `fun2` not forward the args of `fun1` correctly.
Why the int 1 goes to another number but 2.3 still good.
How can I modify my code to implement the forward?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `vprintf` is not itself a var arg function. Therein lies the difference

Comment: Thanks sir. Can I make the fun1 be a var arg function, and fun2 still a var arg function? In my project, fun1 is debug output and fun2 is another level debug output. Thus I want to both be var arg function.

Comment: The typical way is to create two versions. `printf` is usually implemented in terms of `vprintf`. You can do the same for the added flexibility, `fun1` and `vfun1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fun1` needs a list of arguments to match its format, but when call it from `fun2` you give it a `va_list`.  To call it that way you need to rewrite it to take a `va_list` rather than a `...`:

```
void fun1(const char *fmt, va_list args) {
    vfprintf(fmt, args);
}
```

---

If you're using gcc, you can avoid many problems of this nature by using `-Wall` and adding a declaration for your functions that take `...`:

```
extern void fun2(const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
```

This tells gcc that `fun2` takes printf-style arguments starting from the second argument with the first argument as the format.  With this, it will warn you if the arguments passed to `fun1` don't match the format string.

Answer (score 0):

As suggtested by  StoryTeller - Unslander Monica and Chris Dodd, My finial code looks like follows.

```
// before modify
//   vprintf  <-- fun1  <-- fun2


//    after modify

//    vprintf  <-- vfun1 <--- fun1
//                         |- fun2
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
void vfun1(const char *msg, va_list arg_list)
{
    printf("this is vfun1\n");
    vprintf(msg, arg_list);
}

void fun1(const char *msg, ...) // try to forward vprintf, but implemented by call vfun1
{
    printf("this is fun1\n");
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, msg);
    vfun1(msg, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}

void fun2(const char *msg, ...) // try to forward fun1, but implemented by call vfun1
{
    printf("this is fun2\n");
    va_list arg_list;
    va_start(arg_list, msg);
    vfun1(msg, arg_list);
    va_end(arg_list);
}

int main()
{
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    fun1("this is int %d, float %f\n", 5, 2.3);
    
    printf("------------------------------------\n");
    fun2("this is int %d, float %f\n", 5, 2.3);
    return 0;
}
```